# Backgroundworker ReportProgress Firing but ProgressBar isn't changing

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have a progressbar on my form that is not getting updated.

When the Send Email button is clicked I do this:

```
Public Sub SendMail()
    If CheckSettings() = False Then Exit Sub
    BackUpEbillFile()
    LockForm(True)
    StatusBars(1, "Sending emails...")
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = intInvoicesToSend  
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
```

I have the following events:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    e.Result = SendBills()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    Console.WriteLine("I DID IT MA!!!!1 status: " & ProgressBar1.Value)
    ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
    Console.WriteLine("I DID IT MA!!!!2 status: " & ProgressBar1.Value)
End Sub
```

In the SendBills, which is in a mail class, I do this:

```
smtp.Send(msg)
Console.WriteLine("I DID IT PA!!!! count: " & iCount)
frmBilling.BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(iCount)
```

My problem lies at the ProgressBar1.PerformStep() in the ProgressChanged.  I am getting to the progress changed but the Progressbar1 is not changing. It stays at zero.

- intInvoicesToSend is 16
- ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
- ProgressBar1.Maximum = intInvoicesToSend  (which was 16)
- ProgressBar1.Step = 1

Here is my console from the console.writelines:

I DID IT PA!!!! count: 0

I DID IT MA!!!!1 status: 0

I DID IT MA!!!!2 status: 1

I DID IT PA!!!! count: 1

I DID IT MA!!!!1 status: 1

I DID IT MA!!!!2 status: 2

I DID IT PA!!!! count: 2

I DID IT MA!!!!1 status: 2

I DID IT MA!!!!2 status: 3

I DID IT PA!!!! count: 3

I DID IT MA!!!!1 status: 3

I DID IT MA!!!!2 status: 4

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Why does the return not work here? I put intInvoicesToSend is 16 ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0 ProgressBar1.Maximum = intInvoicesToSend (which was 16) ProgressBar1.Step = 1 all on different lines...

Comment: You need either 2 returns (blank line in between), or format differently (as I did in my edit, and put them in a list, since I think it's easier to read...)

Comment: LockForm seems to work well, whatever it does.

Comment: Thanks Reed. I'm not sure what you mean Hans, was that a question? If so, then yes, it just disables a few buttons on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is that you're calling the `ReportProgress` method on the wrong instance.

See this line:

```
frmBilling.BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(iCount)
```

If the BackgroundWorker is defined directly within your form, you can leave off the `frmBilling` portion, and just specify this as:

```
BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(iCount)
```

The way you have it may be causing the `ReportProgress` to get called on the wrong instance...

Comment: Thank you for the response. The reportprogress is being call from another class. Probably not the correct way of doing it but the program wasn't written well, I'm just touching it up. If I removed frmBilling, it doesn't see the BackGroundWorker. Besides, the even is firing off correctly, just not updating the progressbar visually.

Comment: @ErocM: I suspect `frmBilling` is pointing to the wrong instance.  If it's in another class, make sure the caller is setting it up properly in advance...

Comment: You were right. I moved the methods out of the class into my form and moved the references to the frmBilling and I started getting a few cross thread exceptions. I fixed those and everything started working right. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    Console.WriteLine("I DID IT MA!!!!1 status: " & ProgressBar1.Value)
    ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
    Application.DoEvents()
    Console.WriteLine("I DID IT MA!!!!2 status: " & ProgressBar1.Value)
End Sub
```